# How do I use json.dump to display all my data rows instead of just one row Python

Tags: python, json

This is my current code, It fetches all the different data rows and format it to be displayed in json format. However my current code only display a single row data after being run. How do I modify the code so that it would display all the other rows together

```
 rows = cursor.fetchall()
    
    for row in rows:
        print("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
        
        times = row[0]
        Voltage = row[1]
        Current = row[2]
        Temperature = row[3]
        id = row[4]
            
        Response = {}
        Response['times'] = times
        Response['Voltage'] = Voltage
        Response['Current'] = Current
        Response['Temperature'] = Temperature
        Response['id'] = id  
        
            
        responseObject = {}
        responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
        responseObject['headers'] = {}
        responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        responseObject['headers']['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'
        responseObject['body'] = json.dumps(Response)   
        return responseObject
```

Preview of the [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1q7Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer, trying not to modify your code too much. See my comments:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
Responses = [] # <-- list to store all responses
for row in rows:
    print("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
    
    times = row[0]
    Voltage = row[1]
    Current = row[2]
    Temperature = row[3]
    id = row[4]
        
    Response = {}
    Response['times'] = times
    Response['Voltage'] = Voltage
    Response['Current'] = Current
    Response['Temperature'] = Temperature
    Response['id'] = id  
    
    Responses.append( Response ) # <-- adding each response to list
    
        
responseObject = {}
responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
responseObject['headers'] = {}
responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
responseObject['headers']['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'
responseObject['body'] = json.dumps(Responses)    # <-- returning all responses
return responseObject
```